# Queries do not return the relevant documents

Tags: elasticsearch

i have created an index in elastic search and i have put some documents in it. When i write a query to kibana, it doesn't return anything (total=0), though i know there are relevant documents to my query in the index. For example, there is a field named "acronym" and a document with acronym=smartchain, but when i create the query

```
GET /_search
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
       "query":"smartchain", 
       "fields": ["acronym"]
     }
    }
 }
```

and run it, it returns

```
"hits" : {
"total" : 0,
"max_score" : null,
"hits" : [ ]
```

}

Can someone explain me what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your index mappings?

Comment: "mappings": {
   "doc":{
             "properties": {
                 "acronym":{ "type": "text"  }, 
                 "text":   { "type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer", "similarity" : 
                                 "default"},
                 "identifier": {"type":"text"},
                 "rcn":    { "type": "text"  }
      
    }
 }
  }

Comment: Please don't add the mappings in the comment !!

Comment: BTW, there is nothing wrong in the query if the acronym field is of text type unless you're not using any specific analyzer. If any analyzer is used for field acronym then use acronym.keyword in place of acronym in your query.

Comment: So, i have to declare an anayzer for fields that have datatype text, in order to do the search right? Because i have the same problem in the field text, that i have declared an analyzer